# deleting windows update packages on date using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an assignment that wants me to delete all windowsupdatepackages of a specific date.
I came as far as making a script to delete one package at a time using the given KB-numbers. I am stuck now and dont know what do, here's my code:

```
function Uninstall-Hotfix {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        $computerName = $env:computername,
        [string] $hotFixId
    )

    $hotFixes = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computerName -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering | select hotfixid

    $date = Get-Date  

    Write-Host "deleted on '$date'"

    if ($hotFixes -match $hotFixId) {
        $hotFixId = $hotFixId.Replace("KB", "")
        Write-Host "found hotfix" + $hotFixId
        Write-Host "Uninstalling the hotflix"
        $uninstallString = "cmd.exe /c      wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:$hotFixId /quiet /norestart"
        ([WMICLASS]"\\$computerName\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create($uninstallString) | out-null

        while (@(Get-Process wusa -ComputerName $computerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count -ne 0) {
            Start-Sleep 3
            Write-Host "Waiting for update removal to finish ..."
        }
        Write-Host "Completed uninstalling of $hotFixId"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Given hotfix($hotFixId) not found"
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What should I do to make it delete all packages based on date?

Comment: You mention you're stuck.  What are you stuck on?  We can help with your homework.  We can't do your homework.

Comment: What do you see when the run that script? That might help us understand where you're stuck.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error message or anything. it works. I just need to know what I can do to make it delete all packages from a certain date instead of just one package at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a hotfixId string as a parameter, use a date object as an input parameter.  Then have the function compare the date supplied to the function to the dates of the $hotfixes.  The Win32_QuickFixEngineering class has an InstalledOn property that can be used for this comparison.  If the dates match, then uninstall the hotfix.  The exact details of how to do this are your homework, but if you get stuck on a specific point ask another question.

See the documentation on the Win32_QuickFixEngineering class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394391(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot! now I atleast know where to start looking :)